# Script menores de 18

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, css

Estou fazendo um cadastro que só é permitido para maiores de 18 anos, fiz um script que está pegando dois dias a frente no caso hoje e dia 02/11/2017 então só usuário que nasceram do dia 02/11/1999 para baixo podem se cadastrar só que nesse script que fiz está aceitando até a data 04/11/1999, alguém pode me ajudar? segue o código...

```
<?php
session_start();

    echo "<script>
            alert('Jogo para maiores de 18.');
        </script>";

//apartir daqui faz o cadastro do usuario ao clicar no botão cadastrar que receber o nome de btnCadastrar
$btnCadastrar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'btnCadastrar', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if($btnCadastrar){
include_once ("conn/conexao.php");
$dados = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);
$dados['senha']= md5($_POST["senha"]);
//aqui insere os dados na tb_usuario
$result_usuario = "INSERT INTO tb_usuario(permissao, nome, dtnasci, email, senha, saldo)VALUES(
    '".$dados['permissao']."',
    '".$dados['nome']."',
    '".$dados['dtnasci']."',
    '".$dados['email']."',
    '".$dados['senha']."',
    '".$dados['saldo']."'
    )";
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conexao, $result_usuario) or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
if($resultado_usuario):
    echo "<script>
            alert('Cadastrado Com Sucesso.');
            window.location='login.php';
        </script>"; 
else:
    echo "<script>
            alert('Ocorreu um erro ao cadastrar, entre em contato com o administrador.');
            window.location='login.php';
        </script>";
endif;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- As 3 meta tags acima *devem* vir em primeiro lugar dentro do `head`; qualquer outro conteúdo deve vir *após* essas tags -->
<title>Lance Web</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- HTML5 shim e Respond.js para suporte no IE8 de elementos HTML5 e media queries -->
<!-- ALERTA: Respond.js não funciona se você visualizar uma página file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style type="text/css">

    body{ 
        background-color:#0A8AF5;
    }

    /*Aqui se move os botões*/
    .botao{
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: -15%;
    }

    /*fonte da pagina*/
    .font{
        color:white;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .mover{

    }

</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" align="center" >
        <img src="img/logomarca.png" class="img-responsive">
            <form class="form-group" action="" method="post">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <label class="font">Nome</label></label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nome" maxlength="50" value="Digite seu nome" onfocus="this.value='';" style="text-align: center;" required><br><br>

                <label class="font">E-mail</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" maxlength="50" value="Digite seu email" onfocus="this.value='';" style="text-align: center;" required><br><br>


            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <label class="font">Data de Nascimento</label>
                <input class="form-control dtnasci" type="date" name="dtnasci" maxlength="10" onfocus="this.value='';"  style="text-align: center;" required/><br><br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <label class="font">Senha</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="senha" maxlength="8" style="text-align: center;" required><br><br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="saldo" value="0" readonly> <!-- Hidden deixa invisivel -->
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1"> 
                <a href="index.php"><input class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" type="button" value="Voltar"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
                <input class="btn btn-info btn-lg submit-botao" type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="btnCadastrar">
            </div>

            </div><!-- fim div para mover a label e os input basta mudar os números no md e no offset -->
        </form><!-- fim do formulario -->
</div><!-- fim div container -->

    <!-- jQuery (obrigatório para plugins JavaScript do Bootstrap) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- script da idade, usuario menores de 18 não podem se cadastrar -->
<script>
      $('.dtnasci').on('input',function(){
        var dtnasci = $(this).val();
        var data1 = new Date(dtnasci);
        var data2 = new Date(new Date() - data1);
        var idade = (data2.toISOString().slice(0, 4) - 1970);
        if(idade < 18){
            $('.submit-botao').prop('disabled',true)
            $('.resposta-msg').html('Você não pode se cadastrar').show();
        }else{
            $('.submit-botao').prop('disabled',false);
            $('.resposta-msg').html('').hide();
        }
    })
</script>

<!-- Inclui todos os plugins compilados (abaixo), ou inclua arquivos separadados se necessário -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Acontece por causa dos anos pares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

separa a data em um array
ex:

```
$data = [02, 11, 2017];
```

depois começa a verificação do dia atual com

```
if( ($data[2]-date('Y')  ) <= 18 ){
  if( ($data[1]-date('m') ) <=0 ){
    $maior = true;
  }else{
    if( ($data[0]-date('j')) <= 0){
      $maior = true;
    }else{
      $maior = false;
    }
  }
}else{
  $maior = true;
}
```

se for de maior a variavel $maior vai ser true, caso contrário será false

Comment: Como eu colocaria isso no meu codigo?

Comment: cria uma função que envia a data, depois chama ela, tipo, function verificaIdade($data); e essa data é o array que contém o dia,mes,ano, ai no final da function coloca um return $maior, oque irá dizer se é de maior ou nao ai continua o código